# Is there a way to increase the timeout value for a single windows service in the registry in C#?

Tags: c#, service

I am currently doing this below which sets the Services Pipe value as a DWord file in the registry however I am looking to only increase the timeout for a single service through the registry.

```
servicesPipeTimeout.SetValue("ServicesPipeTimeout", 300000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: What service... a Classic Windows Service? what is timing out... The shutdown?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are not a lot of good reason to need this. Maybe you are doing the wrong things on start and stop? Can you explain why you would need to increase the time out?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/622432/how-do-i-increase-windows-service-startup-timeout/622435 The simple answer is: Windows doesn't support to set the timeout individually per service, only globally.

Comment: I second TheGeneral. Chances are high that if you feel you need to do this you are actually trying to cure the symptoms, not the disease.

Comment: If the problem arises in your own self-written service, than you're doing something wrong. Be aware, that the OnStart() method doesn't do the job. It has to start another worker thread that does the work and immediately exit the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for your own service, you should call the api method for requesting additional time in class `ServiceBase`:

```
void RequestAdditionalTime(int milliseconds)
```

You can call this method in OnContinue, OnPause, OnStart and OnStop in case you need more time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0